# No module named 'signxml'

Tags: python, xml, openssl, sign

this is my code :

```
from lxml import etree

from signxml import XMLSigner, XMLVerifier

with open('keys/key', 'rb') as f:
    key = f.read()
with open('keys/certificate', 'rb') as f:
    cert = f.read()
data_to_sign = "<Test/>"
root = etree.fromstring(data_to_sign)
signed_root = XMLSigner().sign(root, key=key, cert=cert)
verified_data = XMLVerifier().verify(signed_root).signed_xml
print("the verified data is", verified_data)**
```

and I succefully installed the lxml with this command:

```
RUN apk add gcc python3-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev musl-dev openssl-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev libpq xmlsec
RUN echo "@edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo "@edgecommunity http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk add xmlsec@edge xmlsec-dev@edgecommunity
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install lxml==4.6.1 zeep==4.0.0 dm.xmlsec.binding xmlsec==1.3.9**
```

but I got this error :

```
 from signxml import XMLSigner, XMLVerifier
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'signxml'
```

Comment: Are you installing `signxml` module?

Comment: No, I think it installed automatically when we install openssl and lxml you can check this documentation:  https://signxml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Have you tried installing `signxml` by hand?

Comment: Yes I try to install it in the container using : pip install signxml but the error persists

Answer (score 0):

finally I solved my problem by adding this command in my dockerfile :

---

RUN pip install lxml==4.6.1 zeep==4.0.0 dm.xmlsec.binding xmlsec==1.3.9 cryptography==2.9 signxml==2.7.2

---